# simple Nginx configuration on t2 (AWS EC2) server gives 504 Gateway Time-out on subdirectories

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, ubuntu-20.04

I have a t2 server (AWS EC2 server) that I want to simply serve an HTML file as the root:

```
http://my_ip/ -> gives me my index.html
```

and another one serving a reverse_proxy

```
http://my_ip/api -> gives me my "API" (or whatever runs on the reverse proxy IP)
```

So I configured the Nginx as the followings:

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

   location /api {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
   }
}
```

Simple enough, in this configuration, my index.html is showing up. But whenever I'm trying to access the "reverse proxy" (/api), I get 504 Gateway Time-out error.

So I tried to "switch places", I gave the reverse-proxy the "root" / and the index.html the "/api".

Getting this configuration:

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {     
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

   location /api {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

This way, the reverse proxy is doing OK! (from /), and when I try to reach index.html (from /api), I'm getting 504 Gateway Time-out error.

So I figured that something is wrong with the "sub-directories" configuration. I tried such configurations on many servers before (mainly from DigitalOcean and others) and never ran into something like that.
My guess is it got something to do with the t2 (EC2) NAT configuration (maybe?). But I'm not so sure.

Googling the issue didn't raise any answers.

There's Ubunutu 20.04 installed on the t2 server, It's "brand new" (nothing was installed but Nginx, Node & NPM - was done by me, "by the book" installations with no needed configurations or file changing).

Note that I don't have a domain yet, I was thinking of trying to server the reverse proxy on a subdomain but I have no way to do it at this point, that's why I tried to do it via a subdirectory.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Aviv, did you solve your problem?, I'm configuring a reverse proxy in AWS and is a truly pain, I've managed to solve lot of issues but still facing problems with subdirectory app.